# XGantt ActiveX issue on Dynamics AX (2012)

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta, gantt-chart, dynamics-ax-2012

I’m facing some issues with the Netronic XGantt ActiveX. My problem is that my ActiveX in the Form doesn’t seem to find the table I specified in the config panel.
I can't post a screenshot here since I'm new (I don't have 10 points) so this is a link to it.[Configuration panel screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/xganttconfig.png/)
I tried with a CSV file storing the nodes information, it works well.

- Is the name SAG_GANTT_SOURCE_MODEL used properly? Knowing that I already created a table with this name and those fields in the screen capture.
- Is there any further configuration elements I need to consider?

I can do as I wish following the classes some Dynamics AX projects (Gantt) uses but it seems to me that it’s too much work for implementing a simple component, isn’t it?
Since I can’t find any documentation/article/tutorial to use the XGantt ActiveX properly (except this one which I already saw http://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/axtechnical/b/axfortechies/archive/2010/05/28/activex-gantt-chart-control-in-dynamics-ax.aspx)
I’m wondering if you have any document, a link or a contact to help me with my issue.
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Netronic. I think they can generate a license file which you can import and this would enable  the disgner of the control. Also they probably still have some pdf documents on thier website.

Comment: I have tried their support and they talk about objects like VcRecordCollection, VcDataRecordCollection. But I can't find these objects on the AOT or the MSDN. For the PDFs I can't find one talking about Dynamics AX.